# Receiving 403 SignatureDoesNotMatch error on Post API for getting resumable error from GCS bucket

Tags: reactjs, axios, google-cloud-storage, http-status-code-403

My project is fully in ReactJS. I am using Axios for API calls.
I am receiving **403** error on post call for getting the resumable url from google cloud bucket.

The full error is: **SignatureDoesNotMatch. The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Google secret and signing method.**

My code is:

```
    axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL}/uploads/authorization`, data, {
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.state.bearer_token
      },
    })
    .then(res => { // then print response status
      axios.post(`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/${res.data.uploadUrl}`, null, {
        headers: {
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
          'x-goog-resumable': 'start'
        }
      })
      .then(res=> {
        console.log("second post response",res.data)
        axios.put(`${res.headers.Location}`, this.state.selectedFile[0], {
          headers: {
            'content-type': this.state.uploadType
          },
          onUploadProgress: ProgressEvent => {
            this.setState({
              loaded: (ProgressEvent.loaded / ProgressEvent.total*100),
            })
          },
        })
        .then(res=> {
          console.log("put response",res.data)
          toast.success('upload success')
        })
        .catch(err => { // then print response status
          console.log("put ERROR: ", err)
          toast.error('upload fail')
        })
      })
      .catch(err => { // then print response status
        console.log("second post ERROR: ", err)
        toast.error('upload fail')
      })
    })
    .catch(err => { // then print response status
      console.log("ERROR: ", err)
      toast.error('upload fail')
    })
```

It is strange that when I pass the same url through postman, it gives correct output. Don't know whats going wrong here?
Could someone help me please.

Comment: The 403 errors usually refer to User permissions, does the account you use have proper permissions to access the bucket?

Comment: @rsalinas I dont have any idea regarding this. If it is permission issue, then how does it not give the same error through postman?? Postman gives the correct desired output.

Comment: It depends on how you are setting the credentials in you program when using the service account to access the bucket. A quick way to test if this is the case, would be to create a public bucket and try to read said bucket. You should get a Stackdriver log of this operation with the service account and no error so you can test if it's a permission issue and know which account is being used

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue?